# Vectors product and equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

Use the vector product to determine a unit vector orthogonal  to each of the vectors a=į_j+k , b=2į+2j+k .hence the equation of the plane which is parallel to the two vectors a and b and passes through the point (1,0,2). State its perpendicular distance from the origin

Comment: Please help me  to find the solve

Answer (score 0):

I not understand how you difined the vector $a$, but the calculation with $a = (1 , -1,1)$. So the vector product of $a \times b$ is $v = (1,1,4)$, therefore the plane equation is $$v.x = v.(1,0,2)$$ that is

$$x + y + 4z = 9.$$

The distance of plane to origem is equal a norm of intesection point of line $t(1,1,4)$ $(t \in R)$ with plane. If $t$ is such, then $$ t+ t + 16t = 9$$, therefore $t = 1/2$. Thefore, the distence this plane to $(0,0,0)$ is

$$\frac{1}{2} ||(1,1,4)|| = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{18}$$.